# Valid solutions of a differential equation $y' + y \cot x = 2 \cos x$ (Tom Apostol's calculus, Vol1 , ex 8.5:8)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Exercise 8.5:8 goes as follows:

> Find all solutions of $y' + y \cot x = 2 \cos x$ on the interval $(0, \pi)$. Prove that exactly one of these is also a solution on $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

The solution $f(x)$ on $x \in (0, \pi)$ has the form:

$f(x) = \frac{f(\frac{\pi}{2}) - 1}{\sin x} + \sin x$

But the confusing part to me is the second part of the problem, where we should find the solution which is also a solution on $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

I understand that if $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(\frac{\pi}{2}) - 1}{\sin x} = 0$, so we are left only with $f(x) = \sin x$, as $x \to 0$. Then if we plug in the $y = \sin x$, the equation $1$ can make sense, because the $\sin x$ in $\cot x$ cancels out, and $y \cot x = \cos x$.

Why is it justified to cancel out that $\sin x$, even though $\cot x$ is not defined at $0$?

Comment: The interval on which the solution is the defined is (0,$\pi)$ so does not include 0.

Comment: Away from $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$ \sin(x) y' + \cos(x) y = \sin(2x), $$
then it is pretty natural to set $f(x)=\sin(x) y(x)$ and write the above DE as
$$ f'(x) = \sin(2x) $$
leading to
$$ f(x) = K-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) $$
etcetera.

Comment: Strictly speaking, since the DE involves $\cot(x)$, some people would say the solution is only truly valid on intervals where that does not have a singularity. Of course, your solution $f=\sin(x)$ makes the DE have a type of "removable singularity" and so some people would also view that as valid for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (as long as they explicitly allow such removable singularities).  And who knows?  Perhaps that DE has a meaningful interpretation in physics where the real-world situation plays out over all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That is an interesting approach, but my question is really in the equation as it is given, because it has $\cot x$ there, so I wonder how can it possibly have a valid solution over all $R$. Is it maybe because the equation $1$ is not valid, but the solution is valid?

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Please note that I added exact wording of the question from the book. Do you have some references where "removable singularity" would be considered fine in some cases, and not in others (because, if I understand correctly, you're suggesting that both options are possible)? Why not write a full answer, so I can close the question.

Comment: @Michael Maybe it is equally important that $f'$ of such $f(x) = \sin x$ is continuous at $0$, so it is a solution on all real numbers?